# Classification of pseudoregular polyhedra

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, polyhedra, polytopes

In contrast to a regular polyhedron, which has one orbit of flags, I’ve been studying what I call **pseudoregular** polyhedra, which have two orbits of flags interchanged by conjugation (explained [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/288152/why-do-some-uniform-polyhedra-have-a-conjugate-partner?r)). Aside from the infinite family of stephanoids, the ones I’m aware of are:

1. The dodecadodecahedron
2. The medial rhombic triacontahedron
3. The ditrigonal dodecadodecahedron
4. The medial triambic icosahedron
5. The excavated dodecahedron

Are there any I missed?

Comment: You are obviously not primarily interested in convex polytopes, but I want to mention that the convex polytopes with few flag orbits (in particular, two orbits) have been classified by Matteo in *"Convex polytopes and tilings with few flag orbits"*.

Comment: Convex polytopes cannot be pseudoregular.

Comment: Convex polytopes can certainly have two flag orbits, so this must be because of this "conjugation". I am not sure what this means.

Comment: Conjugation can be described as replacement of all vertex coordinates by their conjugates while retaining all incidences.